# How do you pronounce "I'm going to buy a cat tomorrow.", in a natural sounding sentence. (in your accent)

Tags: phonology, phonetics

I'm going to buy a cat tomorrow.

Specifically, I'm asking those whose natural accent does not include glottal stopping for a post-vowel t.  Are there two consecutive t sounds between cat and tomorrow, or are the end of cat and the beginning of tomorrow taken up by the same t sound?

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of native English speakers in the world: those who lazily economize on 'T's, gliding into the approaching 'T' without a glottal stop. And then there are those who come to a full glottal stop before pronouncing the oncoming 'T' sound. I belong to the latter sort, equating the former pronunciation with sloth and imprecision. I'm American but I can't help it. This is a personal choice and doesn't have any connection with accent.